# Observable.Iterate lost in the last version

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I've got some code and need to make it work with the latest RX. I've seen that it's recommended to use Create instead of Iterate but  I have no idea how to use Create
Can anyne help with this issue ?

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<Object>> sequence = ...;

disposable = Observable.Iterate(sequence)
            .Subscribe(
                next => { },
                exception,
                ()=>completed(_result));
```

Update:

There is a link to the social.msdn in the comments, I've already seen this thread and didn't find the solution. They provided just some recommendations. I'm not familiar with RX unfortunatelly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Observable.Iterate() in Rx 1.0.10621.0/1.1.10621.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801921/where-is-observable-iterate-in-rx-1-0-10621-0-1-1-10621-0)

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801921/where-is-observable-iterate-in-rx-1-0-10621-0-1-1-10621-0 and the thread here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/rx/thread/527002a3-18af-4eda-8e35-760ca0006b98

Comment: I've seen this answer but to me it misguides because there is not solution on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<Object>> sequence;

sequence.ToObservable()
    .Concat()
    .Subscribe(x => /* ... */);
```